# Mongoose one connection to the db for the whole App

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

i am watching a Nodejs course by Mosh hamedani and i noticed that he used only one connection to mongo db in index.js and used different routes to handle different api calls , this is index.js:

```
 const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const genres = require("./routes/genres");
const customers = require("./routes/customers");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

mongoose
  .connect("mongodb://localhost/vidly") // the db name
  .then(() => console.log("connected to db ..."))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err.message));

app.use(express.json());

//simple routers
app.use("/api/genres", genres);
app.use("/api/cutomers", customers);

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}...`));
```

and this main code and one of get method in  genres.js :

```
 const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

const Genre = mongoose.model(
  "Genre",
  new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      minlength: 5,
      maxlength: 20,
    },
  })
);
router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  const genres = await Genre.find().sort("name");
  res.send(genres);
});
  //other codes
module.exports = router;
```

my question is how genres.js can connect to the same db that is in the index js without the statment of connect,and how it works ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you only have one database. You could create a file for that database, and export the connection once it is established.

For example, you would have `db.js`

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/foo_db');//I would use an environment variable instead of a string for security. 
module.exports = exports = mongoose;
```

Then in your other files, you can just use the connection you have exported.

`getUsers.js`

```js
const db = require('./db.js');
const users_collection = await db.collection('users');
const all_users = await users_collection.find({});
```

---

If you have multiple databases I would suggest creating a connection file for each database. Organized within a folder. With a directory structure something like this

```
- package.json
- <Other files>
---| db
---|--- users.js
---|--- billing.js
---|--- <Other Databases>
```

For example, you would have `db/users.js`

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/users_db');//I would use an environment variable instead of a string for security. 
module.exports = exports = mongoose;
```

Then for your billing `db/billing.js`

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/billing');//I would use an environment variable instead of a string for security. 
module.exports = exports = mongoose;
```

Comment: Exactly that's what i thought but in the course i watched , there is only one connect in the index.js without any export but he could use the db in other routers file (customers.js) directly without any require